# PL/SQL Checking if a record exists within a conditional count in select statement

Tags: select, plsql, conditional-statements, counter

I am trying to browse into a table and retrieve an absenteeism frequency indicator. I already have a query that allows to count number of absences by month. The problem is that i need to compare current record with others (in the same table 'test') to check a condition that would help me for frequency calculation.
My rule for considering a new frequency is: When two periods of sickness aren't consecutive and have a 4 days gap between them.

So, i try to code that using a conditional count() as follow:

```
WITH test (id, start_abs, end_abs, tmp) AS
     (SELECT id, start_abs, end_abs, 0 AS tmp 
      FROM emp_absences
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id, start_abs + 1, end_abs, tmp + 1 
      FROM test 
      WHERE end_abs - start_abs > 0)
      SELECT id, TO_CHAR(start_abs, 'yyyy-mm') AS abs_month, 
             COUNT(DISTINCT start_abs) AS nbr_abs_month,
             COUNT(CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                         FROM test b
                                         WHERE a.id = b.id AND a.start_abs - 4 = b.start_abs)
                        THEN debut_horaire ELSE NULL
                   END) AS frequency
      FROM test a
      GROUP BY 1, 2))
```

I would like to know if it is possible to do so by that way ?
Thanks a lot.

- [More info about Bradford factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradford_Factor)
- [Desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va91m.jpg)
- Oracle version: 12.1.0.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me

```
select Au.Username
      ,Au.User_Id
      ,count(case
               when exists (select 1 from All_Users Au_Aux where Au.User_Id = Au_Aux.User_Id) then
                Au.Created
               else
                null
             end) as count
  from All_Users Au
 group by Au.Username
         ,Au.User_Id
```

I hope help you.
thanks

Comment: You need to explain your answer, not just post bunch of codes

Comment: It seems to work but for me, it takes very long time display results

Comment: Do You have one index in table with the column start_abs?

Comment: Why do you use With? This is used when you need to use this query one more time in another query. Example http://psoug.org/reference/with.html